# How to install tcpdf

Tags: php, composer-php, tcpdf

I am trying to install [TCPDF](https://github.com/tecnickcom/tc-lib-pdf) and I am lost on how to install it correctly.  I've installed PHP libraries via composer before, but I'm not sure what the make commands are for, how to access examples, etc as described in the repo.

As a stop-gap I'm working with an older version as such:

```
{
    "require": {
        "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Comment: Which OS are you running on? Makefile is used to build the library from the source in this repo.

Comment: How is your stop-gap solution using an "older version"? Typically `dev-master` is for bleeding-edge code, not old code.

Comment: I thought so!  The CHANGELOG.TXT within the repo states there is a newer version and points to the git repo, so I figured that was the case.

I am working with an Apache server.

Comment: can you please help how to install ? is we need to install through commands ?

Comment: @fresher I installed it using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/).  The code in my question is what I'm using.